# Multiple ultrasonic sensor interference

Tags: multiple-columns, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am trying to use multiple ultrasonic sensor to develop an estimate of a profile by facing them on the same side and placing them 1 or 2cm away. The problem is a) I have trigger them at the same time b) I cannot change the frequency of the sound. Since the profile is pretty rough, the sound from the one transducer might be sensed by the another transducer also due to scattering. How will I differentiate which echo belongs to which transducer?